# I can not find my.cnf on my windows computer

Tags: mysql, configuration, privileges

My computer is Windows XP.

I need to find `my.cnf` to get all privileges back to the root user. I accidentally removed some privileges of the root user. I still have the password and there is no problem for me to log in to MySQL as the root user. But I can not alter a table.

Answer (score 245):

Here is my answer:

1. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (shortcut for 'run'), type `services.msc`, <kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. You should find an entry like 'MySQL56', right click on it, select properties
3. You should see something like `"D:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="D:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini" MySQL56`

Full answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20136523/1316649

Comment: what happens if mysql is not running as a service? where is the my.ini located? I can see my-default.ini on C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6 but I don't know if the server is using it.

Comment: @PabloPazos Same question, what happens if we run it *not as a service*, but rather from cmdline: `mysqld --console`?

Answer (score 87):

To answer your question, on Windows, the `my.cnf` file may be called `my.ini`.  MySQL looks for it in the following locations (in this order):

- `%PROGRAMDATA%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini`, `%PROGRAMDATA%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.cnf`
- `%WINDIR%\my.ini`, `%WINDIR%\my.cnf`
- `C:\my.ini`, `C:\my.cnf`
- *INSTALLDIR*`\my.ini`, *INSTALLDIR*`\my.cnf`

See also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html

Then you can edit the config file and add an entry like this:

```
[mysqld]
skip-grant-tables
```

Then restart the MySQL Service and you can log in and do what you need to do.  Of course you want to disable that entry in the config file as soon as possible!

See also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: For me it was: `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini`

Comment: I am using xampp and mine is found in C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini

Answer (score 13):

Windows 7 location is: `C:\Users\All Users\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini`

For XP may be: `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini`

At the tops of these files are comments defining where `my.cnf` can be found.

Comment: good one, i check it in Win8 also: " C:\Users\All Users\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6 "

Answer (score 6):

You can find the basedir (and within maybe your my.cnf) if you do the following query in your mysql-Client (e.g. phpmyadmin)

```
SHOW VARIABLES
```

Answer (score 0):

you can search this file : `resetroot.bat`

just double click it so that your root accout will be reset and all the privileges are turned into YES

Answer (score -6):

Start->Search->For Files and Folders->All Files and Folders

type "my.cnf" and hit search.