# Getting "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect" error while connecting to MySQL (wamp server) from JAVA (eclipse)

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, wamp

I have a basic JAVA-MySQL connection class. But, when I execute the code I get

`The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect`

error.

I am using MySQL through wamp server. And, Eclipse is my IDE.

Code (MySQL_connection.java) :

```
import java.sql.*;

public class MySQL_connection {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/error_report","root","");
            System.out.println("Connection success");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I have created error_report database from phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure your MySQL config file does not contain & in the XML.  XML Files must use &amp

Comment: Can you please guide me where I can find that XML file ?

Comment: That question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292769/what-is-the-location-of-mysql-client-my-cnf-in-xampp-for-windows

Comment: There is none & in the file.