# How to properly set utf8 encoding with jdbc and MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, encoding, utf-8

JDBC and MySQL work just fine in my project except when it comes down to accented characters.
This is the URL I use to access the database:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Suppose a `resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery()`, and then a `System.out.println(resultSet.getString("text_with_accents"));`. What's stored in the database is `àèìòù` (note that I've already set the right encoding in the database and all its tables), but what I get is `?????`.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to change your url like

```
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"
```

The `&` must be represented as `&amp;`

Comment: @pr0gma:- Can you check your my.cnf and see if your file has `[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8` present?

Comment: I have no my.cnf. Should I create one? If so, where?

Comment: @pr0gma:- It should be present. You can refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292769/what-is-the-location-of-mysql-client-my-cnf-in-xampp-for-windows to get its location

Comment: Found the my.ini. Double checked, the option was already set in both the client and mysql section.

Comment: `characterEncoding=utf8` --> `characterEncoding=UTF-8`.

Comment: Is there any change to set those attributes at runtime at DataSource creation instead of changing connection string?

Answer (score 0):

Probably...

- you had utf8-encoded data (good)
- `SET NAMES latin1` was in effect (default, but wrong)
- the column was declared `CHARACTER SET latin1` (default, but wrong)