# Cyrillic database contents in Google Sheets JDBC script

Tags: mysql, jdbc, google-apps-script, encoding, google-sheets

Good day everybody, i've encountered a wierd issue with Google Sheets script, where the display and filtering  of a MySQL query is not working due to its contents being in Russian language

I will put the whole script code below, but the main part that doesen't work is:

```
  from samplename_order WHERE status = "Оплачен")');
```

as well as

```
  select (select data_create) as "Дата"
```

In the second example in the column header renders to "????"

In the first example I get nothing at all except column header name.

The whole code:

```
    function onOpen() {

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

var menuItems = [
    {name: 'Sync', functionName: 'readData'}
];
spreadsheet.addMenu('Sync', menuItems);
}


var address = 'xxx:3306'; //ex. '10.1.1.1:1433'
var user = 'xxx';
var userPwd = 'xxxx';
var db = 'sxxxx';

var dbUrl = 'jdbc:mysql://' + address + '/' + db;


function readData() {
 var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
 var stmt = conn.createStatement();
 stmt.setMaxRows(1000);

 var results = stmt.executeQuery('select (select data_create) as "Дата",(select concat(name," ",sername)) as name,mail,(select concat(" ",phone)) as phone,comments,`status` from sample_order WHERE status = "Оплачен"');

  var metaData=results.getMetaData();
 var numCols = results.getMetaData().getColumnCount();






 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();




 sheet.clearContents();

 var arr=[];

 for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
  arr.push(metaData.getColumnName(col + 1));
 }

 sheet.appendRow(arr);


 while (results.next()) {
  arr=[];

  for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {

   arr.push(results.getString(col + 1));
  }
 sheet.appendRow(arr);

}

results.close();
stmt.close();

sheet.autoResizeColumns(1, numCols+1);


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to the `getConnection()` call:

```
?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Question marks and other common character set problems are explained [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

Answer (score 2):

Probably you should use proper **character encoding option** in the connection string.
There is a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33669612/how-to-properly-set-utf8-encoding-with-jdbc-and-mysql) for using utf-8 in such a case.