# mysql: Overwrite Table Data

Tags: php, mysql, csv, pdo

Every 24 hours, I have to add 1 or more rows from updated csv file to my table data.
I've tried this query in my php file:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE mytable;
```

and then insert the new one with this query (PDO):

```
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(:date,:data1,:data2,:data3,:data4,:data5)
```

It's work, but page takes forever to load. 
Is there any solution to update my table, ignore the old and add new row(s) from the updated csv file instead `TRUNCATE` and `INSERT` whole data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just run the insert. You can store an inserted date and query based on that if you want to know what was inserted on a give day.

Comment: How many rows are in the `mytable` before you run the truncate?

Comment: @RiggsFolly About 200 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very fast MySQL way of transfering content from a csv file into a db table is by using [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html).

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "<path-to>/yourfile.csv"
REPLACE
INTO TABLE <db-name>.<table-name>
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(col1, col2, col3);
```

Let it be executed from PHP.

**Notes**:

- Use `IGNORE 1 LINES` if you have a table header in csv.
- The `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','`and `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'` describe how the input fields and lines are formed in the csv file. Customize them to fit your file content's form.
- The last line, e.g `(col1, col2, col3)`, defines the columns in which the input values should be transfered. Because NO primary key or unique index column is defined, then no records will be updated. There will be only insert operations.

Now add a PRIMARY KEY column to the list (let's say it's named `ID_COL`). Or one with a UNIQUE index defined:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "<path-to>/yourfile.csv"
REPLACE
INTO TABLE <db-name>.<table-name>
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(ID_COL, col1, col2, col3);
```

Then, if the `ID_COL` value of a db record is equal with the corresponding csv input value, the record will be updated. E.g. the old values will be replaced - that's what the keyword `REPLACE` is for. Otherwise a new one will be inserted.

Read the LOAD DATA INFILE documentation with patience, so that you understand all the aspects involved in this method. Especially in the second part of it are described the details of customizing the update/insert values using variables.

Good luck!

### Edit:

I just wrote [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45978176/csv-file-upload-to-handle-status-update-inserting-new-records/46005454#46005454) yesterday, which might interest you (about a conditional csv upload).

Comment: Sorry for late late answer. I've tried it. It worked like a charm. Using load data infile seems so much faster than using insert/ replace. Thank yu\ou so much. U have my upvote!

Comment: @nugrohodwiariansyah No problem for the late answer. You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to use INSERT IGNORE?
It will skips the rows which already exists in DB.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO mytable VALUES(:date,:data1,:data2,:data3,:data4,:data5)
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

Comment: I didn't, I'll try it later, the project is in my pc tho. thanks for the answer. I'll inform u when I've used INSERT IGNORE.

Comment: I've try the query using INSERT IGNORE and REPLACE, it's work, but using LOAD DATA INFILE is faster than using INSERT or REPLACE. But thanks for giving me answer.