# After Installing SQL - How and Where do I create a my.cnf file for My Windows OS

Tags: mysql

I'm a beginner to SQL and setting up my environment.

I installed SQL on my windows 10 machine and the next step I need to do is create a my.cnf file (exact instructions: Create a my.cnf file in one of the default locations mysql is looking for it on your OS)

I do not know how and where to set this my.cnf file on my windows 10 machine. Can someone please help?

Comment: maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292769/what-is-the-location-of-mysql-client-my-cnf-in-xampp-for-windows

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html, see section `Option Files Read on Windows Systems`

Answer (score 0):

follow the following steps.
Type services.msc.
Find [MySQL service](http://www.pinoychannel.live/) in the services section.MYSQL56 is SQL service.Right click on it and go for properties.
Under general tab under properties, you will find the path of the default file in the path to executable.
Then locate the MYSQL configuration file i.e my.cnf on windows platform.You will easily find the file in this way on windows platform.

Answer (score -1):

At the same level directory where your project is, create a file Auth and inside that create mysql.cnf .

And in your settings.py give the full path of above file inside databases' default option.