# phpMyAdmin errors logging in

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have seen related questions to this but I can't seem to fix my problem.

When trying to login into phpMyAdmin I got three error messages.

"Cannot log in to the MySQL server"

"mysqli_real_connect(): Server sent charset (255) unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers"

"mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2054): Server sent charset unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers"

I have tried adding

default-character-set=utf8
 to the [mysql] section in my php.ini file. This didn't work.

I am using apache2 on windows 10 with PHP and MySQL. Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Q1: Are you able to log in to phpmyadmin (despite the errors)?  Q2: Have you *EVER* been able to log in?  Q3: Can you log in to mysql itself (from the mysql command line tool)?  If the answers to Q1 and Q3 are "yes", consider just deleting phpmyadmin, deleting the phpmyadmin database from mysql, and doing a clean re-install.  PS: You'd be better served poting these kinds of questions on serverfault.com.  SO is for "programming questions"...

Comment: Yes I can login to mysql. I am a little confused tho as I have a lot of databases installed so I am not sure which one phpMyAdmin is using,

No I have never been able to login to phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below things

Set in my.cnf

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8


[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
character-set-server = utf8
```

Also if you have my.ini both work successful with me.

Comment: Where is my.cnf located?

Comment: /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Comment: I don't have that file on my windows 10 computer

Comment: @User: Patel's response is the same as [PDO::__construct(): Server sent charset (255) unknown to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43437490/).  It's good advice - please try it.  Your Windows/XAMPP my.cnf file is located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292769/): in your XAMPP install folder.

Comment: I didn't use XAMPP i just installed apache2