# Increase `innodb_log_file_size` Through MySQL Command Prompt, Because I don't Have `my.cnf` File

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, innodb

I am using MariaDB on Windows 10. As it is apparent from my question, I don't have `my.cnf` file in my server folder, and I want to change `innodb_log_file_size`. When I change it from command line by doing `SET innnodb_log_file_size=X(some value)`, I get `Variable 'innodb_log_file_size' is a read only variable`. Is there a way I can do it through command line?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292769/what-is-the-location-of-mysql-client-my-cnf-in-xampp-for-windows) helps to find the file. I think configurations from command line are not saved and if server restarts they will be lost, so you should make the configurations in the file

Comment: There is a config file somewhere -- search the entire disk for `my.cnf` and `my.ini`.