# Where can I find the file my.cnf or my.ini file?

Tags: configuration, configuration-files, mysql, database-replication

I've read about MySQL replication and i need to change some configuration but I can't find the file my.cnf or my.ini. I don't know which MySQL version I have but I've downloaded it a long time ago, as a .zip. My box runs Windows 7 64.
Where can i find this file? Should I create it? Where?
Thank you.

Comment: You can find an answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712646/i-can-not-find-my-cnfmysql-configuration-file-on-my-computer

Comment: You can find the answer in the comment that was left earlier, it's also been raised on both serverfault.com and superuser.com, which is why I didn't automatically migrate it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I do not have Window present at the moment, but I think it should reside in the `C:\WINDOWS\` directory.

When invoking help on GNU/Linux with `mysql --help` it shows (excerpt):

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

Maybe you can get the same information on Windows, too.

Btw: with `mysql --version` you can get your current version.

Comment: I tested only under ~/.my.cnf, with no success. But under /etc/mysql/my.cnf it works.

Comment: in my case on rasberry pi, I found binding configuration under \etc\mysql\mariadb.conf.d\50-server.cnf