# Error (with innodb_lock_wait_timeout) in executing a simple query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run a simple query. The query is quite simple but the dataset is large. The query is trying to select all the text that contains specific word and then deleting that row. I am getting the following error.

```
Error Code: 1205. Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

I am using MySQL workbench for my convenience. I am not very familiar with MySQL. I would appreciate any help.

```
DELETE FROM tables WHERE row_names IN (
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT row_names FROM tables WHERE text like "%beer%" 
) AS p
```

)

I ran this query before too and it worked fine.

Comment: I am using only MySQL workbench. So, I tried entering the same code in my query but it did not work

Comment: Where is this file suppose to be at?

Comment: I am not running Linux here unlike the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361437/where-can-i-find-the-file-my-cnf-or-my-ini-file

Comment: What changes should I be making in my-default.ini file. You mentioned wrong file name.