# Build and Deploy fails in Worklight with openjpa fatal general error

Tags: database, deployment, ibm-mobilefirst

I have been facing a nested exception issue for a while now, see below the log details as given. Tested with both Worklight 5.0.5.x and 5.0.6.x:

> Failed deploying application to Worklight Server: The transaction has
>   been rolled back.  See the nested exceptions for details on the errors
>   that occurred.; nested exception is 
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: The transaction
>   has been rolled back.  See the nested exceptions for details on the
>   errors that occurred.

It works fine before adding an environment, but as soon as I add one (tested with the Android and iPhone environments), the error happens.

**System:**

- Windows 7
- Eclipse Juno

Answer (score 0):

try closing Eclipse and deleting WorklightServerHome folder in your workspace.

Comment: It didn't work out Anton, looks like something else is going wrong.

Comment: We've been encountering this exception a few times now.

Arif,
 - does it happen if trying to add any other environment?
 - after the error message is printed, can you check for the filesize of the android/iphone folder that was created?

Comment: True Idan, it only comes after adding the environment before it works fine.

I have just added Android environment and the folder size is 30.2 MB.

Hope to see quick reply as it's been long to stuck in the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In Worklight 5.0.6.1 the application's .wlapp filesize should no longer prevent the deployment process from succeeding. Please upgrade and check again.

If you are using MySQL as your database for Worklight, please follow these instruction: [How to change max_allowed_packet size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062496/how-to-change-max-allowed-packet-size), in order to allow deployment to pass in MySQL.

Comment: I did try that as well Idan and getting the same exception.

Comment: Edit your question with some details: are you using the default database settings in Worklight, or have you changed them, if you did then to which database type? Where is Eclipse located in the filesystem? Does it happen other environments as well?