# can't upload a .pdf file larger than 1 mb ----(ERROR::mysql server has gone away)

Tags: php, mysql

i have written a php code to upload .pdf file into my datbase. the code is working perfect for all pdfs which are less than 1 mb in size.but whenever i am trying to upload a file **larger than 1 mb in size** , **it's failing to upload** and **throwing a error mysql server has gone away.**

**NOTE:: i have changed my php.ini with following changes**

```
post_max_size=128M
upload_max_filesize=128M
memory_limit = 128M
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 300
```

**but it's not solving my problem.the problem remains same** "it's failing to upload and throwing a error mysql server has gone away."
MY PHP CODE IS ::

```
if(isset( $_POST['save']) and $_POST['save'] == "save")
{
  ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 1500);
  include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/include/db.inc.php' ;
  if (!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']))
  {
    echo 'There was no file uploaded!';
    exit();
  }
  /*NOW I HAVE WRITTEN THE PHP CODE TO INSERT THE FILE INTO MY DATABASE.WHAT I CAN
  ASSURE YOU THIS PART IS PERFECT BECAUSE THE CODE IS SUCESSFUL ALL OTHER CASES
  WHICH ARE LESS THAN 1 MB IN SIZE*/
```

**NOTE:: i also used a reconnect while sending the query.so there is not a connection problem**

**EDIT**
there is nothing like `max_allowed_packet` in my my.ini

Comment: What is the **exact** error that MySQP / PHP returns?

Comment: mysql server has gone away

Comment: What type of field are you trying to store the pdf in?

Comment: i think longblb supports file upto 4.3 gb

Comment: I have a pathological dislike of storing binary files in a database. There are usually good reasons why it's a bad idea. Seriously, save the file to disk as a normal file; all the DB needs to know is a path to the file. Saving it to DB introduces all kinds of performance, security and complexity problems that simply don't need to happen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you also have to configure the MySQL server (my.ini on Windows)
make sure there is:

```
[mysqld]
    max_allowed_packet=16M
```

in there - or any sufficiently high number

also note the same problem solved here: [how to change max allowed packet size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062496/how-to-change-max-allowed-packet-size)

Comment: @RitabrataGautam As it is a problem regarding MySQL settings i would say it should be sufficient to restart only the MySQL server

Comment: i am sorry..i have very few knowledge regarding mysql..can u advise me how to restart mysql server

Comment: @RitabrataGautam Assuming you are on Windows XP, go to Control panel / Administrative Tools / Services. There locate the MySQL service in the list and chose to "restart" - or - if you can not find it, after changing the my.ini file restart your computer - the service will restart with it :)

Comment: now what i am going to say is bery surprising.in my "my.ini"..there is nothing like `max_allowed_packet` .... ican't find it

Comment: @RitabrataGautam : That is not surprising at all. That only means mysql is using the default value of 1M - You will need to insert the line max_allowed_packet=16M somewhere into the my.ini file UNDER the section of [mysqld]. Also make sure you do the change in that my.ini file that counts (there may be several copies of it on your harddrive)

Comment: thanks ,thanks and thanks..am literally grateful to u..it was a pain in the neck..solved it..lots of thanks sister

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few things that can cause this, you can get a good overview here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/gone-away.html

You can start by trying this:

```
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 300);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 300);
```

Comment: How long does it take before the error shows up when you run your code?