# Foreach continous loop using file() function.

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

```
$lines = file('array2.txt');
    foreach($lines as $line)
    {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (Tweet, Date) VALUES ('$line', '22')");
    }
```

Hi All,

I am trying to use the code above to use the file() function to add lines from a text file into an array, so I can then place it in a mysql database. The file I am using contains a 100 lines, but using the function above I end up with over 116,000. Does anyone known how what is causing this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Show a few lines of the file data.

Comment: any chance that you file might contain empty lines?

Comment: #PowerdbyFord #Ford #Highboy http://t.co/pMqX
RT @_LiftedTrucks_: #Ford http://t.co/cnrr
`RT @_LiftedTrucks_: #Ford http://t.co/cnrr
RT @_LiftedTrucks_: #Ford http://t.co/cnrr
‚Äö√Ñ√∫@_LiftedTrucks_: #Ford http://t.co/iYUIAZp7hb‚
"@_LiftedTrucks_: #Ford http://t.co/F4FRMbMqC4" I want this @baile` This is a few lines from the file.

Comment: I don't think your problem has anything to do with this piece of code. Post more of your code to give us context.

Comment: Please put array2.txt on PasteBin...

Comment: By the way, you need to escape your $line parameter: `$line = mysql_real_escape_string($line);` Otherwise you will run into problems (injection) when any tweets contain a `'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this way. You will read till file end line.

```
$file = fopen("file.txt", "r");
while (!feof($file)) {
    $line = fgets($file);
    // Code where you make DB INSERT
}
fclose($file);
```

For me this works, and I don't get any other records, only those 10 which i wrote in.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php
$lines = file('array2.txt');
foreach($lines as $line)
{
  if(!empty($line)){
    $values[]= "('".mysql_real_escape_string($line)."', '22')";
  }
}
$query = "INSERT INTO test (Tweet, Date) VALUES ".implode(",",$values);
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

**Note: I suggest to use mysqli or PDO because mysql function depreciated.**

Comment: Hi there, I just tried your code, and I get the following error "MySQL server has gone away"

Comment: `echo $query;` before `$result` and see how the query printed

Comment: @user2694239 Sounds like you've exceeded the [`max_allowed_packet`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062496/how-to-change-max-allowed-packet-size) setting though that can be adjusted.

Comment: Without `mysql_real_escape_string` this answer presumes a lot about the nature of the data being imported.