# How to upload an SQL file if it's greater than 1MB?

Tags: php

When I try to install the ip2country, I get the following message :

Mysql packet size is 1MB and it is lower than the size of the file GeoIPCountryWhois.csv which is 5.85MB. 
Please download the other version of import.php at http://phpweby.com/software/ip2country

In the local server, I can modify the php.ini file, but how about the remote server ?
Do I have to contact my hosting provider and ask him to modify it for me, or there is a way on how can I set this from a PHP code ?

Comment: use this thread
[increase maximum allowed packet size][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062496/how-to-change-max-allowed-packet-size

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of [`BigDump`](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/).

> Staggered import of large and huge MySQL Dumps even through the web
>   servers with hard runtime limit and those in safe mode.