# Is there any sql statement to change max_allowed_packet size in mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to change  **max_allowed_packet** at runtime .using sql statement.
is there any sql statement to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change max\_allowed\_packet size](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8062996)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`max_allowed_packet`
is set in mysql config, not on php side

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=16M
```

You can see it's curent value in mysql like this:

```sql
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet'
```

You can try to change it like this, but it's unlikely this will work on shared hosting:

```sql
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=16777216;
```

You can read about it here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/packet-too-large.html

Comment: To elaborate on "*it's unlikely this will work on shared hosting*", as documented under [Using System Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/using-system-variables.html): "**The [`SUPER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super) privilege is required to set global variables.**"