# How much data can be imported into mysql in one time

Tags: php, mysql, database, file-upload, import

I created a program using PHP to import data into mysql with the uploaded file. I have about 2000 data. But, when I upload a file to 2000 data, only 1983 data is entered into the database and does not display any messages. But when I tried 1000, all of Data entered into the database. So is there any maximum limit of the amount Data that can be imported at a time? or there are other variables that make import data failed on 2000 data?

Comment: not sure tho; but it might be you maximum sql execution time that cuts it off after x seconds

Comment: 2000 rows is usually no problem to import. Which rows are missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062496/how-to-change-max-allowed-packet-size

Comment: May be you are using insert if not exists for some primary key, which may b not unique in your uploaded file.

Comment: Mike M : is there any way to edit maximum sql execution time?
didierc : thank's a lot

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your various timeouts are set high enough... and, without seeing your data or your PHP code, I would venture to guess you're having issues with unclean data.  Many times, an apostrophe (single quote) or some other small data item didn't get handled properly will cause a PHP script such as this to fail.  If it looks like the data that DID make it in is sequential, I would start my search at the 1984th record to see if the data in THAT record has any anomalies or oddities.  Otherwise, see if you can figure out which records aren't making it in, and, try to find similarities.