# Maximum length allowed in GROUP_CONCAT ? How to pass it?

Tags: php, mysql

In mySQL I use GROUP_CONCAT

```
SELECT
visits,
GROUP_CONCAT(token) as token
FROM general
GROUP BY visits
```

but the problem is that I have a huge number of rows with same visits and using PHP it does not allow me to print everything.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: `SET GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN = 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000;`

Comment: I want to know why the downvoter wasted a downvote... it's a good question.

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid ...what?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I mean that you aren't making any sense in your English.

Comment: Given that you have application level code (PHP), I wonder why you need GROUP_CONCAT at all? !?!

Answer (score 9):

I ran into the same issue when I was trying to group_concat a string that was too big.. so what I did to solve it was this

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 10000000000000000;
```

this is a temporary function meaning that it wont actually change it forever but only in the scope of your query session.

I wouldn't recommend changing it forever but only for the scope of your query... that way you aren't using up a lot of memory space for that one function.. when you probably don't need to use it all the time

with that aside if you really want to just reset it to a larger length and not change it for your session then just remove session from the query to set it.

so your query should be like this

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 10000000000000000; -- # -- or whatever size you need to make it
SELECT 
    visits,
    GROUP_CONCAT(token) as token
FROM general
GROUP BY visits;
```

if you are still getting an error as @spencer7593 correctly noted.. you may need to change your **`max_allowed_packet`**... you can do that from this [SO POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062496/how-to-change-max-allowed-packet-size)

Comment: Also be aware that the length of the string returned by `GROUP_CONCAT` function is also limited by the **`max_allowed_packet`** variable.

Comment: I get this error `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING`

Comment: @Fataoulas sounds like there is an error in your php code.. do you know where it is happening? like the line number? its probably because you have too many spaces somewhere..

Comment: does it have to be at the top of the page? the error appears ate the set session...... line

Comment: Are you trying to do both queries in one php call?