# Bash - mysql simple select does not work, returns null

Tags: mysql, sql, bash

I wrote a simple bash script, where I need to get from database 'fake' data, just want to simulate traffic using the REPEAT command. I wrote this line:

```
mysql -u root -p'password' -h x.x.x.x -D mysql -se "SELECT REPEAT('A', 26214400);"
```

Password and login are both fine. I try to connect to remote sql server (its sucessfull) but can't really perform the REPEAT select. What can be wrong and how to solve this?

The output I get:

```
REPEAT('A', 26214400)
NULL
```

I did the same thing in PostgreSQL:

```
"$(psql -h x.x.x.x -d test -U postgres -c $'SELECT REPEAT(\'A\', 26214400);')"
```

which works great, but I also need the mysql solution.

Comment: You are probably generating a string which is too long. Small test with a million 'A' worked fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried your query on MySQL and get this error message:

> Result of repeat() was larger than max_allowed_packet (1048576) - truncated

So you must [change `max_allowed_packet`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062496/how-to-change-max-allowed-packet-size) or use smaller repeat count:

```
SELECT REPEAT('A', 1048576);
```

**EDIT:**

If you need to increase `max_allowed_packet` value, then you must do it on server and on client side:

- to change on server run (or change permanently in *my.cnf*):

  ```
  SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=26214400;
  ```
- to change on client add option `--max_allowed_packet=26M` to *mysql* command line:

  ```
  mysql --max_allowed_packet=26M -u root -p'password' -h x.x.x.x -D mysql -se "SELECT REPEAT('A', 26214400);"
  ```

Specify slightly greater `max_allowed_packet` than is SELECT output size.

More info: [Server System Variables - max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet)

Comment: If there were problem with maxpacket, then postgresql will fail too. But it's works.

Comment: @JevgenijsVaikulis I think on PostgreSQL this limit is greater.

Comment: Changed it but still have the error: `ERROR 2020 (HY000) at line 1: Got packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes`. When I try with smaller repeat value - it works (unfortunately, that's not the solution since I need at least 25 MB of data)

Comment: @yak you must change `max_allowed_packet` limit on client and on server side, see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure your shell command is correct. -p parameter will prompt for password, whereas --password='your_password' will send password to mysql.

Next command is working in my shell:

```
mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 --password='password' -D mysql -se "SELECT REPEAT('A', 26214400);"
```