# IBM Worklight: failed to upload a package using Worklight Console - jpa.entity.ProjectEntity

Tags: mysql, ibm-mobilefirst

I got the error while uploading a package to Worklight using Worklight Console site.

> Object
>   'com.ibm.worklight.dataaccess.jpa.entity.ProjectEntity-com.ibm.worklight.dataaccess.jpa.entity.ProjectEntity-'
>   is not managed by this context

I just saw this error message using Browser Developer Tools to investigate Request and Response Network activity.

PS: There isn´t any JPA class in my project and package.

My environment:

- IBM MobileFirst 6.3 (Worklight)
- IBM WebSphere Liberty 8.5.5
- MySQL
- Windows Server 2008 R2
- Hybrid App with Android Environment

Full error message:

> {"id":147,"type":"UPLOAD_APPLICATION","status":"PENDING","project":{"name":"project1"},"timeCreated":"2015-02-05T19:37:08.000Z","userName":"user1","appServerId":"Liberty","description":{"appVersionsDeployed":[{"applicationName":"App1","environment":"android","version":"1.0"},{"applicationName":"App1","environment":"common","version":"1.0"}],"appVersionsAlreadyDeployed":[],"filename":"App1-all.wlapp"},"errors":[{"date":"2015-02-05T19:37:08.655Z","phase":"VALIDATE","code":"FAILURE","exception":"ArgumentException","details":"Object \"com.ibm.worklight.dataaccess.jpa.entity.ProjectEntity-com.ibm.worklight.dataaccess.jpa.entity.ProjectEntity-2\" is not managed by this context."}],"warnings":[],"productVersion":"6.3.0.00-20141127-1357"}

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the file size (.wlapp). 
I got the error when the file is bigger than 7MB.

Comment: You need to increase the max_allowed_packet_size value in the mysql.ini file.

Comment: It didn´t work. The original value was 256MB (268435456) and I changed to 512MB(536870912) using MySql Console. (set global max_allowed_packet=1024 * 1024 * 512;). I restarted mysql.

Comment: Never tried via the console. Try like here, edit the file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062496/how-to-change-max-allowed-packet-size

Comment: Same error. Changed on my.ini and restart mysql. The original was 256MB and changed to 512MB.

Comment: You are right Tchami...but we are trying to find a solution. The file size is an alternative to worklight works. But not yet the best solution.