# Mysql making --secure-file-priv option to NULL

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am running MySQL in Ubuntu. I getting this error while running specific set of queries.

> The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

When I did `SELECT @@secure_file_priv;` in my mysql server I got `/var/lib/mysql-files/`. I think I need to make this to `NULL`.

This is the query I am running:

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE :file INTO TABLE test_files
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Now the question is how to make this `NULL`?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?. See [secure_file_priv](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv).

Comment: This is my version:  5.7.12

Comment: By the way, I saw this [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv] but I am not aware how to make this NULL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```sql
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.12-0  |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv;
+---------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv |
+---------------------------+
| /var/lib/mysql-files/     |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Change file: `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

```bsh
[mysqld]
.
.
.
secure_file_priv=NULL
.
.
.
```

Restart MySQL.

```sql
mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv;
+---------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv |
+---------------------------+
| NULL                      |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**UPDATE**

```sql
mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv;
+---------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv |
+---------------------------+
| /var/lib/mysql-files/     |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

File: `/var/lib/mysql-files/myfile.csv`

```txt
1,"Row 1"
2,"Row 2"
3,"Row 3"
```

```sql
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test_files`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_files` (
    ->   `col0` INT,
    ->   `col1` VARCHAR(20)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/myfile.csv'
    -> INTO TABLE `test_files`
    -> COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"'
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 3  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT
->   `col0`,
->   `col1`
-> FROM
->   `test_files`;
+------+-------+
| col0 | col1  |
+------+-------+
|    1 | Row 1 |
|    2 | Row 2 |
|    3 | Row 3 |
+------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It did changed to NULL. But still I am getting the same error.

Comment: @PrabhuKhannaMahadevan: Please, update your question and put the query that generates the error.

Comment: Updated the query. I believe there is no issues with the query. It works fine in other servers. It doesn't work only in my local machine.

Comment: It worked after restarting my apache. Great work @wchiquito tnkz a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you wchiquito for your solution, which has led me in the right direction.

I would like to add a solution for **MySQL 8 under Windows 10**. In which a few points differ.

The `my.ini` file can be found in a different location:

```
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.x\my.ini
```

A longer description can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20136523/1316649

The variable to be changed is called `secure-file-priv` and it must be unset.

```
[mysqld]
...
secure-file-priv=
...
```

After restarting MySQL under services you can check with

```
SELECT LOAD_FILE ('C:\\path\\to\\file\\content.txt');
SELECT LOAD_FILE ('C:/path/to/file/content.txt');
```

whether the file is loaded. The content should be visible here, not `NULL`. A simple backslash doesn't work for me.