# how to edit secure_file_priv using MYSQL Docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, cluster-computing, config

I created MySQL cluster of nodes (2 datanodes, 1 management node, and 1 MySQL server node) on Docker Following the instructions from this link:

https://mysqlmed.wordpress.com/2017/09/04/mysql-cluster-in-docker-quick-step-by-step

Then I created a MySQL table to import a csv file (named `daily.csv`) using the command:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Users/Utilisateur/Desktop/daily.csv' INTO TABLE daily IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

and I got the error:

> ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement.

When I add `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ..`

I get this error:

> ERROR 2 (HY000): File 'C:/Users/Utilisateur/Desktop/daily.csv' not found (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)

When i check my `secure-file-priv` using the command:

`SELECT @@global.secure_file_priv`

I get the Following path: `/var/lib/mysql-files/` but I have no idea how to access to it in order to copy my csv file, or even to access `my.ini` MySQL config file to change the variable `secure-file-priv` into `NULL`, which as I saw is another solution to get permissions to access my file.

As I am using Docker, I have no idea how to access the MySQL container config file.

I tried many ways but I see no issue. Could you please help me with this I would be very delighted as I spent a lot of time trying to fix it??

I followed these instructions but don't know where the file `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` to change the variable `secure_file_priv` to `NULL` is:

[Mysql making --secure-file-priv option to NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37543177/mysql-making-secure-file-priv-option-to-null)

Comment: sorry now it's done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case it might be sufficient to mount your local directory inside the directory expected by mysql (`/var/lib/mysql-files/`).

Try starting the container with an additional `-v` parameter, like this:

```
docker run -d -v C:/Users/Utilisateur/Desktop/:/var/lib/mysql-files --net=cluster --name=mysql1 --ip=192.168.0.10 -e MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=true mysql/mysql-cluster mysqld
```

Or copy the file into the folder:

```
docker cp C:/Users/Utilisateur/Desktop/daily.csv mysql1:/var/lib/mysql-files
```

assuming the name of your container is `mysql1`, as in the link you provided.