# Access mysql using shell script

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, ubuntu

I want to login to mysql console and set the max packet variable and then exit from the mysql console. I have written the following:

```
mysql -u root -proot
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=509715201
exit
```

it only login to mysql and doesn't do anything else.

Comment: This might help: [How to change max_allowed_packet size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062496/how-to-change-max-allowed-packet-size)

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

mysql << EOF
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=509715201;
quit
EOF
```

You should use shell's `here documents` to execute sql statement.

Quote from Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide:

> A here document is a special-purpose code block. It uses a form of I/O
>   redirection to feed a command list to an interactive program or a
>   command, such as ftp, cat, or the ex text editor.

Comment: Still it doesn't work. Can you please elaborate EOF.

Comment: EOF is just a tag for shell's here documents. Execute the above shell script, what's your output?@Vivek Sadh

Comment: I think I should also specify username and password to log in. Right ?
I do mysql -u root -proot << EOF and get nothing as output.

Comment: If everything was okay with your SET command there‘s no output.

Comment: I checked value of max packet. It didn't set the desired value. Its showing old value.

Comment: Show output of: `echo 'select @@global.max_allowed_packet;' | mysql -u root -p`

Comment: @@global.max_allowed_packet
509714432

Comment: Everything works fine. Use a number that is a multiple of 1024: 509715456

Comment: Thanks. Multiple of 1024 works. See my answer. I tried using a different command.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I figured it out:

```
mysql -u root -proot -Bse "SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=509715456"
```