# PHP - Unable to upload file even above 1MB and after edited php.ini

Tags: php, mysql

So I made a php file to upload files. This is the code.

HTML:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
<body>

 <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Upload File:
    <input type="file" name="upload" /><br> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
include("config.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit'])  )
{
if ($_FILES['upload']['size'] != 0 ){
$filename = $con->real_escape_string($_FILES['upload']['name']);
$filedata= $con->real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']));
$filetype = $con->real_escape_string($_FILES['upload']['type']);
$filesize = intval($_FILES['upload']['size']);
$query = "INSERT INTO contracts(`filename`,`filedata`, `filetype`,`filesize`) VALUES ('$filename','$filedata','$filetype','$filesize')" ;
if ($con->query($query) == TRUE) {
echo "<br><br> New record created successfully";
}
else 
{
echo "Error:<br>" . $con->error;
}
} else {
$filename = $con->real_escape_string($_FILES['upload']['name']);
$filetype = $con->real_escape_string($_FILES['upload']['type']);
$filesize = intval($_FILES['upload']['size']);
$query = "INSERT INTO contracts(`filename`, `filetype`,`filesize`) VALUES ('$filename','$filetype','$filesize')" ;

if ($con->query($query) == TRUE) {
echo "<br><br> New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error:<br>" . $con->error;
}
}
$con->close(); 
}   
?>
```

But it shows the warning like this.

```
Warning: mysqli::query(): MySQL server has gone away in C:\xampp\htdocs\contractdb\filetest.php on line 29

Warning: mysqli::query(): Error reading result set's header in C:\xampp\htdocs\contractdb\filetest.php on line 29
Error:
MySQL server has gone away
```

Even though I have modify the php.ini file and restarted apache. This is what I have edited in the php.ini file. I only edited this three things only.

```
memory_limit = 32M
upload_max_filesize = 24M
post_max_size = 32M
```

I try to upload the file only above 1MB and it still doesn't work. I want to upload large files. What did I do wrong to get the warning message?

Comment: have you restart php server ?

Comment: do you mean restarting apache? because i already did that many times.

Comment: If you try phpinfo() what do you see?
Put this line in a file and try to browse it.. it will show you if the changes you made have been applied.
<?php
phpinfo();
?>

Comment: I already did that and when i saw the memory limit, upload max filesize and post max size, its the same as I edited. What do you suggest me of checking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you've also set the max_allowed_packet_size in your MySQL settings (read more here: [How to change max_allowed_packet size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062496/how-to-change-max-allowed-packet-size)) and check that you don't have a .htaccess file blocking file uploads of more than 1MB, which might look something like this:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 1M
```

You can always do an ini_get to check if your new php.ini settings have actually been set succesfully: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php

```
echo(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    if($_FILES["photo"]["error"] > 0){
        echo "Error: " . $_FILES["photo"]["error"] . "<br>";
    } else{
        echo "File Name: " . $_FILES["photo"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "File Type: " . $_FILES["photo"]["type"] . "<br>";
        echo "File Size: " . ($_FILES["photo"]["size"] / 1024) . " KB<br>";
        echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"];
    }
    ?>

<?php
if(isset($_FILES["photo"]["error"])){
    if($_FILES["photo"]["error"] > 0){
        echo "Error: " . $_FILES["photo"]["error"] . "<br>";
    } else{
        $allowed = array("jpg" => "image/jpg", "jpeg" => "image/jpeg", "gif" => "image/gif", "png" => "image/png");
        $filename = $_FILES["photo"]["name"];
        $filetype = $_FILES["photo"]["type"];
        $filesize = $_FILES["photo"]["size"];

        // Verify file extension
        $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if(!array_key_exists($ext, $allowed)) die("Error: Please select a valid file format.");

        // Verify file size - 5MB maximum
        $maxsize = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
        if($filesize > $maxsize) die("Error: File size is larger than the allowed limit.");

        // Verify MYME type of the file
        if(in_array($filetype, $allowed)){
            // Check whether file exists before uploading it
            if(file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["photo"]["name"])){
                echo $_FILES["photo"]["name"] . " is already exists.";
            } else{
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["photo"]["name"]);
                echo "Your file was uploaded successfully.";
            } 
        } else{
            echo "Error: There was a problem uploading your file - please try again."; 
        }
    }
} else{
    echo "Error: Invalid parameters - please contact your server administrator.";
}
?>
```

try this above code it  might work.