# max_allowed_packet in mysql_multi instances

Tags: mysql, instances, max-allowed-packet

I hace a mysql server with mysql_multi, so I have to instances mysql1 and mysql2, this two work on diferent ports, when try to consum a soap webservice y get in some ocassions an error like this

```
SQLSTATE[08S01]: Communication link failure: 1153 Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes
```

Then configure the max_allowed_packet directive to mysqld instance, but when try to start mysqld, got a error, and doesnt start, if sombody can help me with this, how can configure max_allowed_packet in mysql_multi instances.

Thanks for the help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062496/how-to-change-max-allowed-packet-size

Comment: *"got a error, and doesnt start, if sombody can help me with this"* First, we will need you to show the config entry you tried, and the error message it generates.