# Can't upload large PDF file into mysql using nodejs express

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am using the `express-fileupload` module to upload pdf files and store into mysql database. I can only upload pdf files < 10mb. I want to allow a bigger bandwidth of files to be uploaded e.g 50mb.

Here is my router:

```
app.use(fileUpload({ limits: { fileSize: 50 * 1024 * 1024 } })); // needed for file upload
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    limit: '50mb',
    extended: true
}));
```

I can see my file is 100% uploaded on the chrome browser upload bar however my app crashes soon after that with this error:

> events.js:183
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>
> Error: Can't write in closed state

I have tried increasing the connection timeout for mysql, i.e to 600000, however still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I fixed it. It was because the maximum packet transfer for mysql connection was by default 4MB. You can change it to a size of your own:

`SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=1073741824;`

Or change it on the `my.ini` file: [How to change max_allowed_packet size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062496/how-to-change-max-allowed-packet-size)

Comment: You know you are setting this value globally to ~1.07Gb?... i would set max_allowed_packet  as a session varariable from the application it self something like  `connection.query("SET SESSION max_allowed_packet = 100000000");` (100000000 bytes = 100Mb) right after you connect to the database.

Comment: Yes, I know. I just added that as an example.

Comment: Expect OOM if you have substantial number of concurrent users when using 1G max_allowed_packet.  Setting Session limit would be in your best interest.