# jdbc connection with remote mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I can't get a solution. my code:

```
package simple;

import java.sql.*;

public class Dbconnect {

    public static Connection Dbconnector() {

        Connection con=null;
        try {
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://www.merinasoftbd.com:2083/merinaso_inventory management?useSSL=false", "merinaso_inventorymanagement", "inventorymanagement");

            System.out.println("Successfully  connected");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return con;
    }
}
```

the  error:

> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large (5,526,600 > 65,535). You can change this value on the server by setting the 'max_allowed_packet' variable.
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:107)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:862)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:444)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:230)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:226)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>       at simple.Dbconnect.Dbconnector(Dbconnect.java:18)
>       at simple.mainclass.main(mainclass.java:13)

Comment: Edit your configuration file(.cnf) or the .ini file on your server. Set max_allowed_packet = 512M and reboot your server.

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: fullexceptionstacktrace:::

Comment: my server doesn't allow to change max_allowed_packet size. says: to change this you have to have super privilege

Answer (score 0):

Your error message indicates that your JDBC client sends a packet to the MySQL server that is larger than the server's max packet size. You can increase the max packet size by following the instructions in the answers to this stackoverflow question:

[How to change max_allowed_packet size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062496/how-to-change-max-allowed-packet-size)

It seems a bit strange however that the driver needs to send a 5 MB packet just to create a connection. But I normally use much larger MySQL packet sizes, so I wouldn't notice. And please take note that the MySQL packet size has nothing to do with IP packet sizes.