# Packets larger than max_allowed_packet are not allowed

Tags: mysql

We are having several problems with this error:

Packets larger than max_allowed_packet are not allowed

Each time we see this error in our websites we have to restart de MySql Service.

Our software is developed in .Net 4.5 with the last mysql connector 6.9.11, Mysql Server 5.6.41. 
We have increased the max_allowed_packet=1G in the my.ini [mysqld] and checked if it really has this value with the show variables like 'max_allowed_packet'; query. It's still happening.

We don't have blobs, images and anything on our database big enoguh to to reach this value. The biggest value in our database is just 210K and we don't do almost inner join queries.

What should we do? We've tried everything... even adding the the max_allowed_packet=100M to the [mysql] section.

Why is this still happening?

Many thanks

Comment: You may need to restart your MySQL server after updating the `my.ini` file.  Also, please read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062496/how-to-change-max-allowed-packet-size) which may be of help to you.

Comment: I tried it many times @Tim