# How do i import database in mysql ? I am using laradock and I am not being able to increase the import file size of mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, laradock

I am not being able to increase the file upload size in phpmyadmin. I am using laradock and I have already increased `post_max_maxsize` and `upload_max_filesize` value in `php-fpm` laradock. I have already built after changing those values with `--no-cache`.

Comment: Try setting SET @@GLOBAL.wait_timeout=30000 through MYSQL CLI/QUERY.

Comment: Also refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062496/how-to-change-max-allowed-packet-size.

Comment: I solved it by copying the exported database to docker container and import it using cli

Comment: for laradock there is laravel.ini inside php-fpm folder where we can edit upload size and other value and need to rebuilt php-fpm using --no-cache and restart nginx and phpmyadmin