# Download binary file from MySQL as an executable

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
    include_once 'dbconnect.php';

    $query = "SELECT * " . "FROM download WHERE username = '" . $username . "'";

    $stmt = $conn1->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $blob = $result[0]["File"];

    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=download.exe");
    header("Content-length: " . strlen($blob));
    echo $blob;
```

I have this code, when it downloads the executable is only 1 MB while the file should be 13 MB

Comment: Set the appropriate headers and deliver the content - just like any other resource...

Comment: Ohhh... check the max packet size of the database (both client and server!). If the field content exceeds this limit, you'll need to fetch packets repeatedly until you get the entire contents of the field. On a local dev machine I would first try to increase this to see if it would fix to problem.

Comment: PhpMyAdmin is not a database, it's a web-based application for querying and managing MySQL databases. The database is MySQL.

Comment: @HonkderHase How do you fetch a single row repeatedly? I don't think there's any API for that. You just have to increase the `max_packet_size` parameter.

Comment: It's actually `max_allowed_packet` ...not sure if config names might vary on MariaDB.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change max\_allowed\_packet size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062496/how-to-change-max-allowed-packet-size)