# How to set max connections in mysql permanently?

Tags: mysql, database-connection

I need some help to set MAX connections value permanently in MySql. I have tried but I can't find a permanent solution. Now, I am using temporary solution by changing in command prompt like in [this article](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/update-max-connections-mysql/).

Comment: You should take this to [dba.se]

Answer (score 14):

Since this question shows up on the search results when people search for a solution, and now that the solution has changed, I felt it necessary to post an answer.
Ubuntu 15.04+ [no longer respects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30901041/can-not-increase-max-open-files-for-mysql-max-connections-in-ubuntu-15) the limits set in `/etc/security/limits.conf`. So if you set max connections and you don't see any effect, have a look at the log file at `sudo vim /var/log/mysql/error.log` and you'll see `Changed limits: max_connections: 214 (requested 5000)`.

**Solution:**
Copy the limits for mysql from the systemd config file to `/etc/systemd` using:

```
sudo cp /lib/systemd/system/mysql.service /etc/systemd/system/
sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service
```

Then add the following lines to the bottom of the file:

```
LimitNOFILE=infinity
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
```

You could also use a finite number instead of infinity.

Now reload systemd config:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Comment: Your answer fixed my warning for Ubuntu 16.04, thanks! But I applied only a part of it:  **ADD=> /lib/systemd/system/mysql.service**
     *LimitNOFILE=infinity*
     *LimitMEMLOCK=infinity*
    **sudo systemctl daemon-reload** AND 
    **sudo systemctl restart mysql**

Answer (score 4):

Thank you Very much i inserted the code into the MY.ini file and it solved the problem.

in c:/xampp/mysql/bin/my.ini file under the [mysqld] section i inserted the following line

**

> max_connections = 250

** 
 Later restart the xampp server to take effect.

if we give set-variable=max_connections=250 Mysql server is not starting.

Once again thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, the `set-variable` syntax is old, was deprecated, and doesn't work in recent versions of MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem using Ubuntu 16.04.
Had to do it this way:

```
sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service
```

Added the lines at the bottom of the file:

```
LimitNOFILE=infinity
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
```

Reloaded systemd config:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Increased the number of files the system could open:

```
ulimit -n 4096
```

Edited my.cnf like this:

```
vi /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

Looked for the max_connections and changed it´s value to 20000.

To make sure the settings become permanent performed a mysql service restart:

```
 sudo service mysql restart
```

Went to phpmyadmin and checked the max_connections global variable using:

```
SHOW VARIABLES like '%max_connections';
```

It worked - Now when the daemon restarts I have the same max_connections that I had before.

Comment: `vi /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` only thing which worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: on windows, i am am unable to find the cnf files.

Answer (score 1):

you can set that in my.cnf, [Mysql Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/too-many-connections.html)

I quote

```
You can increase this value in main config file (e.g., /etc/my.cnf or /etc/mysql/my.cnf) using this syntax:
[mysqld]
set-variable=max_connections=250
```

i think you need to restart mysql after changes to take effect.

Comment: but these lines are not available in my.ini file. Can i add these lines and if i can where should i add. Xampp dies not have a cnf file instead it has my.ini file.

Comment: i think they should be there, if they are not add the line
set-variable=max_connections=250
under [mysqld] section.

Comment: i am unable to find this configuration file on windows, i have only /bin/mysqlId file

Comment: @IrfanNasim have you checked this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712646/i-can-not-find-my-cnf-on-my-windows-computer