# Can not increase max_open_files for Mysql max-connections in Ubuntu 15

Tags: mysql, performance, ubuntu

I am running this version of Mysql

```
Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.24, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)
```

On this version of Ubuntu

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
```

This is the config I set for Mysql:

```
key_buffer_size     = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
innodb_buffer_pool_size=20G
innodb_log_buffer_size=16M
tmp_table_size = 32M
max_heap_table_size = 32M
open-files-limit=4510
max_connections=500
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
query_cache_type=1
query_cache_limit   = 32M
query_cache_size        = 32M
```

These are the warnings I keep getting when starting MYSQL:

```
2015-06-17 17:28:53 26720 [Warning] Buffered warning: Could not increase number 
of max_open_files to more than 1024 (request: 4510)

2015-06-17 17:28:53 26720 [Warning] Buffered warning: Changed limits: max_connections: 
214 (requested 500)

2015-06-17 17:28:53 26720 [Warning] Buffered warning: Changed limits: table_open_cache: 
400 (requested 2000)
```

I already tried these steps:

1) Adding this to `/etc/security/limits.conf`

```
mysql           soft    nofile          65535
mysql           hard    no file          65535
```

2) Adding this to `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` and `/etc/pam.d/commom-session`

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

3) Add this to `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

```
open-files-limit=4510 or open_files_limit=4510
```

None of these have worked and I am still not able to raise the mysql max connections to 500.

I'd really appreciate some help at this point.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: http://mysql-forum.ch/showthread.php?tid=7

Comment: Hey @BK435, thanks for sharing the link. Sadly, I tried with the steps there and keep getting the same warnings and not being able to increase **max_open_files** or **max_connections**.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Ubuntu has moved from Upstart to Systemd in version 15.04 and no longer respects the limits in /etc/security/limits.conf for system services. These limits now apply only to user sessions.

The limits for the MySQL service are defined in the Systemd configuration file, which you should copy from its default location into /etc/systemd and then edit the copy.

```
sudo cp /lib/systemd/system/mysql.service /etc/systemd/system/
sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service # or your editor of choice
```

Add the following lines to the bottom of the file:

```
LimitNOFILE=infinity
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
```

You could also set a numeric limit, eg `LimitNOFILE=4510`.

Now reload the Systemd configuration with:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Restart MySQL and it should now obey the max_connections directive.

I also had problems stopping MySQL cleanly after upgrading to 15.04. If this affects you (you'll know because it will take 300 seconds to time out when you do `service mysql stop` or `service mysql restart`) then adding the following line to the same /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service file fixed it for me:

```
ExecStop=/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf shutdown
```

This latter problem seems to have been fixed by 16.04 and this line is no longer required, so before you do a distribution upgrade you'll want to stop MySQL and remove the `ExecStop` line from the config file.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Matt, for such a clear explanation. You saved the day and night, sir!

Comment: Somtimes you just have to experience the exact issue to really know what to do in that environment...glad you jumped in to help Matt, +1

Comment: One of the best solutions.

Comment: `LimitMEMLOCK=infinity', for what it is ? why it is not possible to set a numeric limit for LimitMEMLOCK?

Comment: As far as I know it is possible to set a numeric value for either argument.

Answer (score 21):

As of MySQL 5.7.7, this is what the documentation recommends for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7, Oracle Linux 7, CentOS 7, SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12, Fedora 24 and 25:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-systemd.html

On Ubuntu 16.04 the service is called mysql, not mysqld, so this is what I did:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.d
sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.d/override.conf
```

Added this in the new file override.conf:

```
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=5000
```

Then restarted the service:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart mysql
```

Comment: After trying just about every other solution under the sun that I found while Googling/reading on this topic, this one finally worked! Thanks!

Comment: This is pure gold! Thanks @Fredrik.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you don't copy the existing mysql.service file as suggested, just create a file with only the changes you care about. So do:

```
mkdir /lib/systemd/system/mysql.service.d
vim /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.d/limits.conf
```

And the contents of limits.conf is simply:

```
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=10000
LimitMEMLOCK=10000
```

or whatever limits you prefer.

Comment: I think `/lib/systemd/` is a typo in the first line, should it be `/etc/systemd/`?

Comment: Worked well except on my system the service name is mysqld.service  instead of mysql.service so I had to match that when creating the new directory that holds the limits.conf file.

Answer (score 4):

With systemd the file override.conf does not need to be searched for or possibly created. Just use the following command:

```
sudo systemctl edit mysql
```

If the file override.conf exists, it is read in, otherwise it can be created now.

The rest, as Frederik wrote: Enter LimitNOFILE and restart the services.