# Increasing mysql max_connections to 1024 in a docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, amazon-ec2, database-connection, amazon-ecs

I want to increase `max_connections` to 1024 in a docker container of [mysql 5.6](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) hosted on [AWS EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/tw/ec2/). The instance type of the EC2 is `m4.large`.

I've set max_connections to 1024 by adding `max_connections=1024` in `my.cnf`, but I only saw 214 when typing `show varialbes like 'max_connections';` mysql command. Here is the `my.cnf` I have.:

*my.cnf*

```
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
skip-host-cache
skip-name-resolve
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp

max_connections=1024
max_connect_errors=100000

# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
#bind-address   = 127.0.0.1

#log-error      = /var/log/mysql/error.log

# Recommended in standard MySQL setup
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES                                                                                                                                                                       

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

I've tried the solution mentioned in [MySQL Max_connections stuck on 214 ?](https://codepoets.co.uk/2015/mysql-max_connections-stuck-on-214/). But this one doesn't work in my case. The following are my settings:

*common-session*

```
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
session [default=1]         pam_permit.so
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
session requisite           pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
session required            pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
session required    pam_unix.so 

session required    pam_limits.so
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

*limits.conf*

```
#<domain>      <type>  <item>         <value>
* soft  nofile 65536
* hard  nofile 65536
* soft  nproc  100000
* hard  nproc  127466
```

I've also tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30901041/can-not-increase-max-open-files-for-mysql-max-connections-in-ubuntu-15).

*mysql.service*

```
[Unit]
Description=MySQL Community Server
After=network.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
User=mysql
Group=mysql
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld_safe
ExecStartPost=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
TimeoutSec=600
Restart=on-failure

LimitNOFILE=infinity
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
```

This solution doesn't work for me either.

I pass the above files from the host machine into the docker container by using `mountPoints` and `volumes` in task definition of ECS.

Here are the mountPoints and volumes of my ECS task definition:

```
"mountPoints": [
{
  "containerPath": "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/user.sql",
  "sourceVolume": "user",
  "readOnly": true
},
{
  "containerPath": "/etc/mysql/my.cnf",
  "sourceVolume": "mysql_config",
  "readOnly": false
},
{
  "containerPath": "/etc/security/limits.conf",
  "sourceVolume": "limits_conf",
  "readOnly": null
},
{
  "containerPath": "/etc/systemd/system/mysql.service",
  "sourceVolume": "mysql_service",
  "readOnly": null
},
{
  "containerPath": "/etc/pam.d/common-session",
  "sourceVolume": "common_session",
  "readOnly": null
}
],

"volumes": [
{
  "host": {
    "sourcePath": "/home/docker/mysql/user.sql"
  },
  "name": "user"
},
{
  "host": {
    "sourcePath": "/home/docker/mysql/my.cnf"
  },
  "name": "mysql_config"
},
{
  "host": {
    "sourcePath": "/home/docker/mysql/limits.conf"
  },
  "name": "limits_conf"
},
{
  "host": {
    "sourcePath": "/home/docker/mysql/mysql.service"
  },
  "name": "mysql_service"
},
{
  "host": {
    "sourcePath": "/home/docker/mysql/common-session"
  },
  "name": "common_session"
}
],
```

What else can I do so that `max_connections` can reach 1024?

If you need to know more information of my docker container, just let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I find out that adding `--ulimit nofile=65536:65536` solves my problem.

The first 65536 in the option represents soft limit, and the second 65536 represents hard limit.

Answer (score 0):

For Amazon ECS Task Definition this could be done with:

[image: [CMD Parameters]
[image: Resource Limits]