# "Host 'xxx.x.xx.xx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"

Tags: mysql, database, connection

In C#,  windows forms, I'm trying to connect to a web server (for testing, 000webhost.com) and whatever I do it keeps saying "Host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server" (where the X's are my WAN IP address).

If I do this on localhost, then it works perfectly fine, but whenever I try to connect to a database on any web server that exception gets thrown. Why does it do that and how can I fix it?

Comment: mysql username is host based in the syntax `user@hostname_or_ip`. This error means your user don't have permission to connect from the host you are trying to connect. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/adding-users.html

Comment: are you trying to connect as root, or another user?

Answer (score 1):

You must configure the MySQL server to allow connections from other computers than local host only.

Answer (score 1):

probably there's a mysql configuration which prevents you from connecting outside localhost.
you have to bind all addresses permitted to connect to the server and comment out or delete line relative to skip-networking.
open your my.cnf configuration file (depends on machine you are on) but it should be on

> /etc/mysql/my.cnf

delete bind-address line or set it to this value:

```
bind-address 0.0.0.0
```

comment out or delete it:

```
#skip-networking
```

reboot mysql server:

```
service mysql(d) restart
```

now you should be able to connect to it from any host.

Comment: Where can I find /etc/mysql/my.cnf file?

Comment: what o.s. are you running?

Comment: Windows 7 Ultimate, Service Pack 1

Comment: it should be here: C:\Users\All Users\MySQL\MySQL Server X.X\my.ini
where X.X is mysql version

Comment: Nope, directory "All Users" doesn't exist and i've done a full search on "my.ini" file and nothing has been found. The location is actually here: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\ and there's a file called "my-default.ini". Maybe that's the one?

Comment: if it is the only configuration file with these directives, yes, it should be the one

Comment: no, it doesn't seem the configuration file: is there a bin folder in that path? maybe inside there is my.cnf configuration file

Comment: No, in the bin folder are just a bunch of .exe and .pl files.

Comment: right, don't you see any my.ini in basic installation folder?

Comment: Ah hell, I finally found it thanks to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712646/i-can-not-find-my-cnf-on-my-windows-computer) . Now I tried to do what you told me but bind-address line isn't even there and skip-networking has already been commented. Now what? :/