# change mysql listening (bind) address on windows

Tags: mysql, windows

I'm using MySQL for Windows (installed through Oracle's official setup utility), and I don't want MySQL to accept connections that are NOT coming from a specific host (in this case it's a certain domain). Been using Linux before and thus I know that there was something about `my.cnf` where I simply had to change the `bind-address` value. However, I cannot find this file using Windows. Any tips for me?

Comment: There are docs for Windows too. Have you considered reading them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can not find my.cnf on my windows computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712646/i-can-not-find-my-cnf-on-my-windows-computer)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Have a look here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html

It gives you all the positions and reading sequence of MySql configuration files in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

with mysql 8 on windows 10, you can edit with admin privileges the file: **my.ini**
in the directory:
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0

remark: you can find this path via properties of service, as it is referenced in commandline:
[image]

in section: [mysqld]
set (it might not exist so add the line):
bind_address=127.0.0.1

Restart windows service:

```
sc query MySQL80
sc stop MySQL80
sc start MySQL80
```

then check via netstat that binding adress

```
    netstat -abn

  TCP    127.0.0.1:3306        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [mysqld.exe]
```