# Communications link failure with jdbc and mysql in remote connection

Tags: java, mysql, remote-access, remote-connection

I am trying to insert data from a java file into the mysql database which is installed in another system.

This is my java file

```
package serverDemo;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.util.Scanner;

import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;

public class TestIn {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the values");
        System.out.println("id:  ");
        int id = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("name:  ");
        String name = sc.next();
        System.out.println("age:  ");
        int age = sc.nextInt();

        try {
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.43.116:3306/datacollect","root","spectrum7tech");
            System.out.println ("Database connection established");

            /*Statement stmt=(Statement) con.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate("insert into ser_test_detail.details("+id+",'"+name+"',"+age+")");*/

            PreparedStatement st=(PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO datacollect.namedetails(id, name, age) VALUES(?,?,?)");
            st.setInt(1,id);
            st.setString(2,name);
            st.setInt(3,age);
            st.executeUpdate();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
             System.err.println("Got an exception! "); 
             System.err.println(e.getMessage()); 
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The given hostname is of the another system containing mysql database.

I am getting exception details in console

```
Enter the values
id:  
24
name:  
easrdtfghj
age:  
23
Got an exception! 
Communications link failure

Last packet sent to the server was 1 ms ago.
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Last packet sent to the server was 1 ms ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2103)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:718)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:302)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:282)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at serverDemo.TestIn.main(TestIn.java:24)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: LAPTOP-6JMVNJOQ
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:243)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:280)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2026)
    ... 12 more
```

I have tried with IP address instead of hostname.

How can I establish the connection?

Please, help me out.

Comment: Is the machine with `MySQL` installed on the same network as you?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15707789/2310289

Comment: Is it necessary to connect both system in same network?

Comment: In most simpler cases, YES. If the database server and your system are not behind the same router (in the same network) the database server will need a `static public ip` so that machines outside the network can connect to it

Comment: The public ip should be set in db url?

Answer (score 0):

1) go to my.cnf

2) Comment bind-address(As it is accepting  to local connections only)

"bind-address            = 127.0.0.1"

to

"#bind-address            = 127.0.0.1"

3) Restart  mysql

Comment: Thanks but please say, where should I find the my.cnf?

Comment: Please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712646/i-can-not-find-my-cnf-on-my-windows-computer

Comment: It's first time, I am facing this problem, do I have to modify the my.cnf file?

Comment: Yes as you can see bind-address is set to accept connections only from local host so it not allowing you to connect from remote machine change it to 0.0.0.0 or just comment it

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. I got 6 files named as 'my.cnf' and there is no any word named bind or address.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76511/mysql-enable-remote-connection-in-centos-my-cnf-does-not-have-bind-address-to-co