# How do I turn on the Event Scheduler in MySQL if I don't have my.cnf or my.ini?

Tags: mysql

Total novice to this, so be gentle. All I need to do is turn on the event scheduler. I know I can use a command like (SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 1;) but I don't seem to have either of the files you would normally add the command to (my.cnf or my.ini). I'm looking all through the C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\ directory but they aren't there. If I try to turn on the scheduler through phpMyAdmin, it says I need a super privilege, which I also don't know how to set.

This is a VPS provided by Godaddy if that makes a difference. I didn't install or set up MySQL on it, so I'm using whatever defaults they give you.

I've heard that I can create my own my.ini, but I have no idea what to put in it.

Also, the only .ini I see is my-default.ini. Can I edit this or copy it?

Comment: Perhaps you should have windows explorer set to show you hidden files.

Comment: Already tried this. They just aren't there.

Comment: It is just very unlikely that you don't have the ini file. [Please check the locations in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712646/i-can-not-find-my-cnf-on-my-windows-computer)

Comment: I've checked all those locations. Also ran a search on the whole server. Those files don't exist.

Comment: That is odd, but I haven't tried running Mysql outside of Linux, except through Xampp. I would suggest, then, creating a my.ini in one of those locations and restarting the service to see if it picks it up. I would imagine it will.

Comment: I tried copying the my-default.ini and renaming it as my.ini, then added the SET command to it, but it didn't work. Even after restarting the service. I just don't know enough about what I'm doing.

Comment: I think you are on the right track. Insure that you stuck that line in the [mysqld] section of the my.cnf and give it another restart.