# Mysql - How do I find "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" in WIndows 7 with out using XAMPP

Tags: mysql, windows, config

What is the location of `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` mysql in windows 7 I already search and tried but I have this answer

`C:\Windows\my.ini C:\Windows\my.cnf C:\my.ini C:\my.cnf C:\xampp\mysql\my.ini C:\xampp\mysql\my.cnf C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.cnf`

I am not using **Xampp**.

Comment: If you're not using xampp, why check in those directories?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can not find my.cnf on my windows computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712646/i-can-not-find-my-cnf-on-my-windows-computer)

Comment: @MattBall for reference only

Comment: @MattBall duplicate no it is not, im not using xampp, only mysql 5.7

Comment: Try the search box in the upper right corner of the file explorer.

Comment: @O.Jones I already did that search